# Converting JavaScript function to a VBA function

Tags: javascript, vba

I have this JavaScript Function that works:

```js
var char = 10;
    function grc(len) {
        if (len < 1) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (len == 1) {
            return Math.pow(char, 5);
        }
        return Math.pow(char, len - 1) + grc(len - 1);
    }
        console.log(grc(5));
```

Non-working Javascript?

```js
var char = 10;
function grc(len) {
    if (len < 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (len == 1) {
        return Math.pow(char, len);
    }
    return Math.pow(char, len - 1) + grc(len - 1);
}
    console.log(grc(5));
```

And I need it in VBA, I gave it a try but I'm not good in VBA:

```
Function GRC(length)
If (length < 1) Then
    GRC = 0
  End If
        
If (length = 1) Then
    GRC = char ^ length
  End If
  
  GRC = char ^ (length - 1) + GRC(length - 1)
    
  End Function
```

But it doesn't Work, I'm trying to write this in excel so not really getting any useful errors. its supposed to work like this:

the GRC function would need to know the "characters" variable and take in the "length" variable, in java-script I just created the "characters" variable above the function so the function could call on to it. But in this scenario I'm using VBA and in excel which I don't know if there is a way to get a variable from the spreadsheet without taking it in to the function. as far as the expected output goes
if:
char = "10", "length" = "5"
then the output would be: 111,110
if:
char = "52", "length" = "3"
then the output would be: 143,364

the algorithm that it's using is from https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm

Comment: Why are you saying it does not work? Remember to add test data, expected output, actual output and any error you are getting while using your code. Don't hesitate on looking thru the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) or in 
the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be sure about how to ask questions

Comment: Java is not JavaScript. Assuming your first paragraph is JavaScript, it still is invalid. Variable names cannot have hyphens, and `number-of-characters` makes no sense. This looks more like pseudo code, but even then it has undefined references.

Comment: I used hyphens just because it was an example. But I fixed it

Comment: What is `numberofcharacters`? It is undefined.

Comment: It's usually defined before the function

Comment: apologize for being a noob at asking questions and formatting them

Comment: I edited your question: Wrapped the JS version into a snippet, so it can be run on the spot. Added a value for `numberofcharacters` (10), and a run with argument 5. Returns 11120.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that the function doesn't return immediately when you assign a value to the function variable, so `GRC = 0` is not equivalent with `return 0` in the JavaScript version.

Instead, use an `Else If` chain:

```vb
numChars = 10

Function GRC(length)
    If (length < 1) Then    
        GRC = 0
    ElseIf (length = 1) Then
        GRC = numChars ^ length
    Else
        GRC = numChars ^ (length - 1) + GRC(length - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: not sure why but this isn't giving the expected output if: char = "10", "length" = "5" then the output should be: 111,110 but its 11,120

Comment: its give an output though so that's better than what I had before

Comment: Your JavaScript version is also returning 11120. See in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvgtr374/) (open the little console widget to see the output of 11120). So the VBA version is doing what the JS version is doing.

Comment: OK you're right it does and it's extremely confusing because the java script in this case it was in HTML. Still gives the correct output and the code is identical and I can't track down why it's giving different results Here: https://bookmarkletserver.000webhostapp.com/github/PasswordEntropyCalculator.html

Comment: Your question was to convert a piece of JS to VBA. Asking us to dissect an external website's functioning is another question and is one that is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: OKAY I updated the code snippet now explain to me how that's any different from what it was before and why that's getting a different result

Comment: all I did was swap out variables for actual numbers

Comment: But you cannot replace `len` with a hardcoded number. Every recursive call `len` is a different value. First it is 5, but then the next call it is 4, ... until it hits a base case when `len` is 1. Are you saying it should be hard coded? Then hard code it also in VBA? Same thing. Then you'll also get 11110. This is becoming a different question... One about understanding how recursion works.

Comment: no it shouldn't be hard coded. but if you go to that HTML page and without even looking at the code just use it after enabling GRC it gives the result I'm talking about while being a variable and being able to be manipulated by the function

Comment: just enable GRC and type: 12345 Which is charset of 10 and length of 5

Comment: also try the same thing: 12345 on https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm

Comment: Thanks for the help, just had to work through it. not sure how it would output in normal VBA but in excel the Edited Answer works perfectly

Comment: OK, not sure what you mean with the Edited Answer, as I never edited my answer after I posted it, but good to hear you got it working!